Как сделать свой атрибут, который обновляет значение свойства
Хочу сделать атрибут, который будет обновлять значения свойств, как в библиотеке ReactiveUI.
[Reactive] public string Text { get; set; }

А при развернутом положении можно было дать дополнительную логику и вызывать метод обновления, уже не используя атрибут.
string text;
public string Text 
{
    get => text;
    set
    { 
        доп. логика...
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref text, value);
    }
}

Как можно сделать подобное со своим атрибутом, если кто знаете подскажите пожалуйста, или наведите на статейку или тему, где можно почитать изучить.

Зовется Генерацией кода (Source Generators). Конкретно генерацию указанного атрибута можно глянуть тут. Другими словами, атрибуты ничего не делают, это просто пометка конкретного объекта, а вот где-то там есть код, который генерирует другой код и внедряет в ваш проект (обычно это .g.cs файлы в папке obj (вроде).

В старых версиях там вообще у них используется Fody, он вообще жуткую магию творит (вот), но суть +- схожа, ищется атрибут, если он есть, "дописываем" нужный код за человека, готово. Вообще, если вам надо поменять значения, то вряд ли это к генератору кода. Ну а если задача создать атрибут, который создаст код, то советую задуматься о целесообразности, ибо зачастую (особенно на маленьких проектах), проще написать руками, чем автоматизировать это.

Понял, спасибо изучу

Пример кода, как работать с Source Generator. Класс наследующийся от ISourceGenerator должен располагаться в проекте, нацеленном на .net standard 2.0.
Как дебажить генератор в Visual Studio IDE: https://github.com/JoanComasFdz/dotnet-how-to-debug-source-generator-vs2022
Как дебажить генератор в Rider IDE: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/07/13/debug-source-generators-in-jetbrains-rider/

Консольный проект (SourceGeneratorTest), его .csproj
 <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
     <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
     <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
     <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.10.0" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
   <ProjectReference Include="..\SomeSourceGenerator\SomeSourceGenerator.csproj"
                     OutputItemType="Analyzer"
                     ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"/>
 </ItemGroup>


Библиотека с генератором (SomeSourceGenerator), его .csproj
 <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
     <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
     <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>Generated</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
     <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
     <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.1.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.3" PrivateAssets="all" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
     <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
 </ItemGroup>


Библиотека с кастомным атрибутом (Core), его .csproj
 <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
     <LangVersion>11</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>



Пример кода генератора:
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;

namespace SomeSourceGenerator
{
    [Generator]
    public class SourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
        }

        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            var compilation = context.Compilation;
            var assembly = compilation.Assembly;
            var module = assembly.Modules.First();
            foreach (var namespaceMember in module.GlobalNamespace.GetNamespaceMembers())
            {
                foreach (var namespaceTypeMember in namespaceMember.GetTypeMembers())
                {
                    var sourceBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    sourceBuilder.Append($@"
public class {namespaceTypeMember.Name}Generated
{{");
                    bool hasAttribute = false;
                    foreach(IPropertySymbol propertyMember in namespaceTypeMember.GetMembers().Where(m => m.Kind == SymbolKind.Property))
                    {
                        var attributes = propertyMember.GetAttributes();
                        if (attributes.Length > 0 && attributes.Any(attribute => attribute.AttributeClass?.Name == nameof(SomeAttribute)))
                        {
                            hasAttribute = true;
                            
                            var privateVariableName = $"_{char.ToLowerInvariant(propertyMember.Name[0])}{propertyMember.Name.Substring(1)}";
                            sourceBuilder.Append($@"
    private {propertyMember.Type} {privateVariableName};
    public {propertyMember.Type} {propertyMember.Name}
    {{
        get => {privateVariableName};
        set
        {{
            {privateVariableName} = value;
            /* Какой-то код */ 
        }}
    }}
");
                        }
                    }

                    sourceBuilder.Append($@"}}");
                    if(hasAttribute)
                        context.AddSource($"{namespaceTypeMember.Name}Generated.g.cs", sourceBuilder.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Определение кастомного атрибута:
public class SomeAttribute : Attribute { }

Код основного консольного проекта:
using SomeSourceGenerator;

namespace SourceGeneratorTest;

public class SomeFirstClass
{
    [Some] public string Text { get; set; } = null!;
    [Some] public string Message { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class SomeSecondClass
{
    [Some] public string SomePropFirst { get; set; } = null!;
    [Some] public string SomePropSecond { get; set; } = null!;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
    }
}

Что сгенерировалось:
public class SomeFirstClassGenerated
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            /* Какой-то код */ 
        }
    }

    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get => _message;
        set
        {
            _message = value;
            /* Какой-то код */ 
        }
    }
}

public class SomeSecondClassGenerated
{
    private string _somePropFirst;
    public string SomePropFirst
    {
        get => _somePropFirst;
        set
        {
            _somePropFirst = value;
            /* Какой-то код */ 
        }
    }

    private string _somePropSecond;
    public string SomePropSecond
    {
        get => _somePropSecond;
        set
        {
            _somePropSecond = value;
            /* Какой-то код */ 
        }
    }
}


Это решения типа Metalama/Postsharp, которое заключается в постобработке .NET сборки согласно заданным вами правилам, например, по разворачиванию кода.
Вот тут обсуждается в чём-то похожая тема. То есть запрашиваемое там протоколирование может быть реализовано с помощью постобратоки - в каждый метод будет вставлено неколько дополнительных команд
    ParameterInfo[] args = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
    MY_Debug_Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, args, [arg1, arg2], this);

где, среди прочего, будут автоматически (а значит без ошибок) вставлены в вызов протоколирования аргументы метода.
Кстати, диспетчеризация / проксимизация является альтернативой постобработке, и у каждого подхода есть свои минусы и плюсы.
Тут много ссылок на решения для аспектно-ориентированного программирования.
Aspect-oriented programming in .NET with AspectInjector
Introduction to Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) in .NET with Autofac Interceptors

А с какого, хочется спросить.

"Это правила типа SO" - дало что либо? Мне - нет, как собственно и ваш ответ. SO не форум, SO это место, где люди собирают полезные вопросы и качественные ответы на них, тут не обсуждают и не дают пустые ссылки. Даже если почитать справку, там четко написано - "оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание"... "сегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию ... на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт". Короче, пользы от вашего ответа сейчас 0, да и даете вы платное, да и весьма сложное решение, которое явно не подойдет новичку.
